# Groovy syntax error

Tags: groovy

I have an error ("unexpected token"). I don't know Groovy very well , but how to fix it? Part of my code:

```
def PriorityQueue&lt;Agent&gt; agentPQ = new PriorityQueue&lt;&gt;(agents.size(), new Comparator&lt;Agent&gt;() {
    @Override
    int compare(Agent o1, Agent o2) {
        if(o1.issueCount == o2.issueCount){
            if(o2.lastAssignedTime == o1.lastAssignedTime){
                return o1.user.name.compareTo(o2.user.name)
            }
            else{
                return o1.lastAssignedTime.compareTo(o2.lastAssignedTime)
            }
        }
        else{
            return  o1.issueCount - o2.issueCount
        }
    }
})
```

I have an error in &lt case

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is caused by HTML entities that encoded `<` and `>` characters:

```
def PriorityQueue&lt;Agent&gt; agentPQ = new PriorityQueue&lt;&gt;(agents.size(), new Comparator&lt;Agent&gt;() {
```

It should be:

```
def PriorityQueue<Agent> agentPQ = new PriorityQueue<>(agents.size(), new Comparator<Agent>() {
```

The code you have pasted wont compile neither in Groovy nor in Java.